# Taking Values From One Table and Using These In a Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, dynamic-columns

I'm unsure how to title exactly what I am trying to do so let me just start with an example.

Say one table in my database contains all restaurants in the system that can grow at any time.  All records in this table are unique.  For the sake of argument, lets say the restaurants' table looks like this

```
 ID | Customer Name
----|--------------
 mc |  McDonalds
 bk | Burger King
 wd |   Wendys
 sw |   Subway
```

Now I'd like to some how dynamically take this and make them columns in a select statement where I will call a scalar function to return some value. I should note my end goal is to produce a line graph using another 3rd party control to display relevant quantitative data per day for something like total sales.

Using the above restaurants table, the select statement would read with each row a decimal for the total sales that day:

Basically, I'd like a return set to look like this to easily stick this into the chart control I'm using.

```
    Date    |  McD's  |  Burger King |  Wendys  | Subway
------------|---------|--------------|----------|-------
 11/01/2013 | $507.68 |    $300.01   |  $567.99 | $423.56
 11/02/2013 | $667.98 |    $202.55   |  $864.35 | $143.36
```

and so forth

I don't need help writing a function, just pointed in the right direction on how to have a dynamic set of columns.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your data, but I think you may want to look into [Pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  Lots of examples of it here as well.

Comment: Wouldn't you just do this with a PIVOT?

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned my SQL knowledge isn't advanced.  To be honest, I've never used Pivot before.  Thank you for this suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Restaurants') Is Not Null Drop Table #Restaurants
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Sales') Is Not Null Drop Table #Sales

Create Table #Restaurants(
ID int,
Name varchar(50)
)
Insert Into #Restaurants Values
(1, 'McDonalds'),
(2, 'Burger King'),
(3, 'Wendys'),
(4, 'Subway')

Create Table #Sales(
ID int,
SaleDate Date,
Amount decimal(18, 2)
)
Insert Into #Sales Values
(1, '20131115', 1000),
(1, '20131116', 1500),
(2, '20131115', 500),
(2, '20131116', 800),
(3, '20131115', 700),
(3, '20131116', 600),
(4, '20131115', 2000)

Declare @PivotList varchar(max)
Select @PivotList = COALESCE(@PivotList+ ', ', '') + '['+Name+']'
From #Restaurants

Declare @Query nvarchar(max) = 'Select *
From(
Select SaleDate, Name, Amount
From #Restaurants a
Join #Sales b On a.ID = b.ID
) a
Pivot(
Sum(Amount) For Name In ('+@PivotList+')
) As PVOT'
Execute (@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most tools which are designed for presenting this kind of information are designed to take in flattened data sets. You would approach this by writing your query without trying to dynamically generate the columns and instead just work on getting your data out of the database and into the hands of the control.

This would look something like this for your data set:

```
11/1/2013 BK $1,355,243.23
11/2/2013 BK $253,546.45
11/1/2013 WD $2.24
```

What you do at that point is place your date in the rows, your restaurant header into the columns, and an aggregate function in the cell.

This particular functionality exists in SQL Server Reporting Tools and numerous other 3rd party visualization tools. I would expect this to exist in yours as well.